# How to pass a json-like environment variable to docker run

Tags: json, docker, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to pass this variable : `REGION={'code': 44, 'name': 'grand_est', 'pretty_name': 'Grand Est'}`
to `docker run`.

The exact command is:

```
docker run \
 -e "REGION={'code': 44, 'name': 'grand_est', 'pretty_name': 'Grand Est'}" \
 meteocovid
```

But I get the error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
```

I can't split the variable REGION into separated variable because the docker container needs it in this exact format and I can't rebuild the variable within the container.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you sure you tried the exact command you mention? as `docker run -e "REGION={'code': 44, 'name': 'grand_est', 'pretty_name': 'Grand Est'}" debian /bin/bash -c 'echo $REGION'` works for me…

Comment: Just base64 for the value and handle it in your docker image.

Comment: @ErikMD, I double checked and I have the exact thing ...

Comment: @JerylCook, It does work in Base64 thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
docker run \
 -e REGION="{'code': 44, 'name': 'grand_est', 'pretty_name': 'Grand Est'}" \
 meteocovid
```

You are now passing a string of the "object" which you can then parse in whatever language you're using.

Comment: OK but IINM in bash, `program foo="bar…"` and `program "foo=bar…"` are parsed exactly the same way… aren't they?

Comment: It is working but I had to customise the json parser I'm using in python. The easy fix was : docker run \
-e REGION="{\"code\": 44, \"name\": \"grand_est\", \"pretty_name\": \"Grand Est\"}" \
meteocovid